# Bulk edit files in file manager

Tags: cpanel

I want to bulk edit multiple files in file manager.

I don't want to download edit and then after that reupload files, it takes too much time.

I need some plugin,online software or a way to bulk edit multiple index files in cpanel file manager.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you in advance